# Does a new small-engine carb need to be adjusted?

Tags: carburetor, small-engine, replace

(Stihl FS55 string trimmer)

After years of regular use, the engine degraded fairly suddenly to barely keeping alive, uselessly low power, and running very rich.  For reasons good or not, I decided to replace the carb.  This didn't change anything.

Hence, the question: should the factory-set carb be good-to-go, or is it expected that it will need adjustment?

Comment: With my B&S mower engine, it wasn't the carb itself that needed adjusting, but the automatic throttle, which is controlled by a flap sensing the pressure in the air intake. It needed cleaning, as well as the associated links and springs outside the carb. It also needed a new spark plug. When that was failing the poor combustion made it seem like it was a bit rich.

Comment: Is this a well used engine that may have lost compression? Dirt getting past the air filter may create premature cylinder,  piston and piston ring wear to lower compression. Two ways to determine wear; complete disassembly or pull starting to feel compression. If pull starting, remember how it feels with plug wire off then remove spark plug and add some oil into cylinder and put plug back on. Pull again without plug wire to feel if higher resistance occurs. Extra oil helps seal rings for higher compression unless the cylinder wall, piston or rings are scored, well worn, damaged.